# How can I downgrade a system that accidentally had backports installed?

Tags: apt, configuration, downgrade, backport, system-settings

I installed a fresh Ubuntu system.  Somehow - possibly through my own error - the backports repository got enabled.  Then I did several upgrades.  I noticed that this happened when networking suddenly stopped working, "Network Settings" now has an "(alpha)" in the title bar, "System Settings" → "Network" now displays an error dialog saying "The system network services are not compatible with this version".

Now, I've disabled the backports repository, and I'd like to restore my system to its previously-functional state.  My question is twofold:

1. How do I determine which packages were installed from backports?
2. Can I automatically re-install all those packages (and purge their configuration) to get back to a sensible state?

If the answer to 2 is "no" I can probably manually purge some things and reinstall, but it would be nice to have it handled automatically.

### Update:

It wasn't an update that broke the network; it was `apt-get install indicator-network`, which installed something called "`connman`" and *removed* `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome`.

Nevertheless I am leaving the question up, since I am still interested in how I can purge packages from a particular source after accidentally adding that source, and how I can determine which packages were installed from where.

Comment: have you tried one of the questions that discusses ppa-purge?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu have you started from, and what version do you have now?

Comment: if a backport has broken something, then this should be reported against the appropriate backports project (see the projects list here: https://launchpad.net/ubp).

Comment: @aking1012: nope. link?

Comment: @mikewhatever: fresh install of precise.

Comment: @micahg: Maybe the comment about backports in `sources.list` should say that instead of "WILL NOT receive ... any [security] updates" :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you've upgraded to Precise, it has the backport repository enabled by default, however, nothing should have been installed unless selected.

From the [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop)

> Backports are now more easily accessible -- to enable users to more easily receive new versions of software, the Ubuntu Backports repository is now enabled by default. Packages from backports will not be installed by default — they must explicitly be selected in package management software. However, once installed, packages from backports will automatically be upgraded to newer versions.

Comment: I believe you, but, how could I query apt to reassure myself that this is the case?